# open multiple inset panel does not work in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to open multiple inset axis in a figure.
However I get the following warning message and only the last inset panel is plotted.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py:106: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
  warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
```

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

fig, ax= plt.subplots()

iax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 2])
ip = InsetPosition(ax, [0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2]) #posx, posy, width, height
iax.set_axes_locator(ip)
iax.plot([1,2,4])

iax1 = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 2])
ip = InsetPosition(ax, [0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]) #posx, posy, width, height
iax1.set_axes_locator(ip)
iax1.plot([1,2,4])
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the warning seriously and do as it suggests in

> Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.

namely, use a unique label for each axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

fig, ax= plt.subplots()

iax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 2], label="iax")
ip = InsetPosition(ax, [0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2]) #posx, posy, width, height
iax.set_axes_locator(ip)
iax.plot([1,2,4])

iax1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 2], label="iax1")
ip = InsetPosition(ax, [0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]) #posx, posy, width, height
iax1.set_axes_locator(ip)
iax1.plot([1,2,4])

plt.show()
```